# How can I get the current frame of a Lottie animaion?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, lottie

I have been searching for a way of getting current frame of a Lottie animation using Xamarin forms, but I had no success so far.

Does anyone know a way do that?

Comment: What do you mean get current frame ?Do you mean you want to stop on a frame or get an image on a frame.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT In some moments I need to know what Frame is being played so I can do something like ```animation.PlayFrameSegment(animation.currentFrame, ToFrame)``` . In my case, when a carousel is rolled back, I need play from current frame to a specific previous frame, not from the final of animation to that frame.